# Хранение ключа в программе

Tags: c++, шифрование, aes

Можно ли хранить ключ в открытом виде в виде переменной при выполнении программы? То есть, есть зашифрованные AES при помощи ключа юзера данные. Пользователь вводит пароль, из него генерится ключ, и дальше в течение длительного времени происходит работа с данными при помощи этого ключа. Но если хранить ключ в виде переменной, то, мне кажется, его очень легко извлечь, например, из дампа памяти. Насколько безопасен такой подход?

Comment: по моему все просто. пока для работы программы ее значение нужно -  придется хранить и в каком виде значения не имеет. даже если вы этот ключ зашифруете и будете ненадолго  расшифровывать то из дампа памяти возьмут в зашифрованном виде и посмотрят алгоритм расшифровки в том же дампе. надо минимизировать риск какого либо доступа на машину при котором возможно получить дамп памяти программы